# NHibernate and SQL Server 2012 Sequences

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sql-server-2012

How well does NHibernate work with SQL Server 2012 sequences? I see that SQL Server finally has sequences which can be very beneficial in my current project. I see that NH has support for other databases but didnt see any support for SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me that NHibernate 3.3.1 (very recently released) has support for sequences in SQL Server 2012. I imagine that mapping sequences in SQL Server is the same as mapping them in PostgreSQL and Oracle, so you might wanna give it a try.

[NH 3.3.1 announcement](http://sourceforge.net/news/?group_id=73818)
  [Changelog for NHibernate 3.3.1](https://nhibernate.jira.com/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10000&version=11140)